# React Native: Can't import local files/components

Tags: react-native

In my react native cli project I am having trouble importing local files.

I just created the project using cli and it was working fine. I ran it in my mobile and it showed the default welcome message. Then I made `src` folder, `components` folder in it and created a Header component.
As soon as I imported the header component in App.js and used it it showed this errror message in my packager console.

```
Bundling `index.js`  [development, non-minified]  0.0% (0/317),failed.
error: bundling failed: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `./src/components/Header` from `/home/sagar/workspace/native/my_expences/App.js`: could not resolve `/home/sagar/workspace/native/my_expences/src/components/Header' as a file nor as a folder
at ModuleResolver._loadAsFileOrDirOrThrow (/home/sagar/workspace/native/my_expences/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:337:11)
at ModuleResolver._resolveFileOrDir (/home/sagar/workspace/native/my_expences/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:222:17)
at ModuleResolver.resolveNodeDependency (/home/sagar/workspace/native/my_expences/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:236:19)
at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/home/sagar/workspace/native/my_expences/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:111:14)
at dependencyNames.map.name (/home/sagar/workspace/native/my_expences/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:136:10)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at ResolutionRequest.resolveModuleDependencies (/home/sagar/workspace/native/my_expences/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:135:42)
at Promise.resolve.then (/home/sagar/workspace/native/my_expences/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:175:21)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

The error goes away if I remove the Header component and the import statement.
Please help

#### Edit:

It turns out it is having trouble importing file with jsx extension. I changed the extension to js and the error went away.
So, How can I import jsx files.

Comment: Can you show that import snippet on your question?